# Sublime Text change 'Goto Line...' shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3

(This question is specifically for the Mac, but you may enlighten Windows users if you want!)

What is the command for 'Goto Line...' to change the shortcut as it's down for 'Goto Definition...' like below:

```
[
    { "keys": ["cmd+D"], "command": "goto_definition" }
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find out what command is being executed by opening the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) and entering

```py
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Keeping the console open, select **`Goto -> Goto Line...`** or hit the key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and the following appears:

```js
command: show_overlay {"overlay": "goto", "text": ":"}
```

Therefore, the keymap definition would be:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+g"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": ":"} }
```

You can change the `"ctrl+g"` to whatever you want in your user key bindings.

Comment: @MattSMo, I don't get this point we need paste or { "keys": ["ctrl+g"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "text": ":"} }