# User key bindings in Sublime Text 3 doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, key-bindings

I'd like to customize some of the Sublime Text 3 keybindings to mimic IntelliJ IDEA. One of them is opening a file from the current project, also known as [Goto Anything](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_navigation.html#goto-anything) in Sublime jargaon. I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33695784/839733) answer to find out that the default key binding for "Goto Anything" is `⌘ + p` on a Mac, like so:

```
{ "keys": ["super+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} }
```

I added a new keybinding as follows:

```
[
    { "keys": ["shift+shift"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} }
]
```

It, however, doesn't work; pressing `shift` twice in rapid succession does precisely nothing. When I open the console, I see the following message:

> Unable to open /Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/Default/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap

According to [this](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1433) ticket, this message is harmless but misleading, and is just an indication that Sublime is opening a file.

What's wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here; I found [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/map-double-tap-shift-key-to-command/25636) post in Sublime blog.

> ST doesn't support using only modifier keys in a keybinding.